# No link to controller/action when using tag helper

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have the following in my _layout.cshtml:

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
   <li><a asp-area="" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Index">Home</a></li>             
</ul>
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
   <li><a asp-area="" asp-controller="User" asp-action="Index">User</a></li>
</ul>
```

And I have both controllers and both actions - neither have any attributes.  The first link works as expected and I can step into the index action on the home controller when clicked.

Intellisense in the _layout page can see the controllers and actions and I can F12 to both.

But the second link is failing and all I get is localhost:12345/.

I've tried the full asp-route="User/Index" with the same result.  I can navigate directly to localhost:12345/User/Index and hit the break point in the controller.  This must be something silly, but for the life of me (and two others) we can't see it.  Any help much appreciated.

From Startup.cs:

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "default",
        template: "{controller=User}/{action=Index}/{id?}"
    );
});
```

Comment: What do you mean by _failing_? What error are you getting?

Comment: is `/User/Index` by any chance the default route in your application?

Comment: Can you share default route config to determine problem better?

Comment: @Stephen "all I get is localhost:12345/"  -  i.e. there is no User/Index on the end

Comment: Then I assume that is your default route

Comment: Yep - thought that was the silly thing as soon as I posted the edit - thanks.

Comment: Well its not _failing_  - that is what its supposed to generate :)